# Why do physicists comes up with special names for change in quantities?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, terminology, soft-question

I only have a basic understanding of physics, so this may be a naive question. I've noticed in my self-study that when referring to the change in some quantity $Q$, instead of just calling it *change in $Q$* and using the symbol $\Delta Q$, they'll come up with a different name and symbol.

For example, a change in temperature $U$ is heat $Q$, a change in momentum $p$ is impulse $J$, a change in energy $E$ is work $W$, and so on. Why is this?

Comment: This isn't a question about physics, it's a question about why people like to name things they refer to a lot: why talk about velocity rather than rate-of-change-of-position-with-time, for instance?

Comment: The tag is "terminology". So, don't be rude.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking why we use certain notations are off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/50583).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat is actually a change in thermal energy, not temperature, but more broadly the answer to your question is that the things you've claimed are names for changes in quantities are really *contributions* to those changes. For example, if you can hear an object you move make a sound, the work you're doing on the object is a contribution to the change in its energy, but there's also a negative contribution coming from the sound production. Similarly, if a fast train collides with a slower one in front of it that's accelerating, the change in the front train's momentum over a period including the collision combines the impulse from the train behind with the change in momentum due to the front train's engine accelerating it.

Comment: Also consider that Q must flows to keep something not isolated at a constant T. The concept is different, not terminology